# Variable assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, variable-assignment

variables a, b, c and d all need to be set to 'foo'.

Is there a way to accomplish this in one swooping assignment?  Like:

a, b, c, d = 'foo'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ref [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929356/is-it-right-to-assigning-multiple-variable-like-this-a-b-c-d-5-in-ruby)

Best way to do it as follow as you need common value to all your variables

```
a= b= c = d = 'foo'
```

for different value you can do

```
a, b, c, d = 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4'
```

Comment: Also: `a, b, c, d = ["foo"] * 4`

Answer (score 3):

I believe Ruby supports the normal type of chained assignment, like:

```
a = b = c = d = 'foo'
```

Comment: Be careful, because this will point all the variables at the same actual string in memory. So, if you then did `a.reverse!` then a, b, c,  and d would ALL be 'oof'.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = b = c = d = 'foo'
```

is surely the correct way to do it... If you want a bit a freaky way:

```
a,b,c,d = %w{foo}*4
```

(*%w{foo}* returns a string array containing *foo*, **4* multiplies this array so you get an array containing 4 times the string *foo* and you can assign an array to multiple comma-separated variable names)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be safest way:

```
a, b, c, d = 4.times.map{'foo'}
```

This one is similar and is a wee bit shorter:

```
a, b, c, d = (1..4).map{'foo'}
```

It may be longer than using an array multiplier or chained assignment, but this way you'll actually get different objects, rather than different references to the same object.

Verification code:

```
[a,b,c,d].map(&:object_id)
```

If the `object_id`s are the same, your variables are referring to the same object, and mutator methods (e.g. `sub!`) will affect what all 4 variables see. If they're different, you can mutate one without affecting the others.