# Ruby: Assigning Variables in Groups

Tags: ruby, variables, variable-assignment

Is it possible in Ruby to name variables in groups, possibly like this?

```
(variable1, variable2, variable3) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`variable1 = variable2 = variable3 = 0` may be safe for integers, but since in ruby everything is an object, these will all actually point to the same object. For other types, some operation may end up converting one to a duplicate, but you can't assume that will be the case, and you may end up inadvertently modifying all of them at once.
For example, if you're using strings:

```
variable1 = variable2 = variable3 = "hello"
variable1.upcase!
puts variable1
puts variable2
puts variable3
  >>> HELLO
  >>> HELLO
  >>> HELLO
```

Much safer is parallel assignment:

```
variable1, variable2, variable3 = 0, 0, 0
```

**Edit**: edited a couple sentences for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below :

```
 variable1 = variable2 = variable3 = 0
```

**Read This question** :- [**`is it right to assigning multiple variable like this a = b = c = d = 5 in ruby?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929356/is-it-right-to-assigning-multiple-variable-like-this-a-b-c-d-5-in-ruby)

So generic approach is:

```
 variable1, variable2, variable3 = [0] * 3
```